# What is the difference between Tether & USD Coin?

Tags: cryptocurrency

How are Tether (USDT) & USD Coin (USDC) different and what advantage is there to using one over the other or are they the same? Tether has a somewhat shady past & is no longer backed 1:1 by physical dollars as they used to claim. Is the same true for USD Coin?

Comment: What research have you done?  (This site is populated by people who love fiat money.)

Comment: I searched it on google but didn't find anything explaining the difference. I saw other cryptocurrency related question here, so I figured it was OK to post it here. Is there a cryptocurrency specific SE?